# R: Selection probabilities with panel users (complex survey data)

Tags: r, survey, weights

I am calculating the weights for a survey, but I don't know what to do with my selection probabilities.

Let's say I want to ask people from some country what their opinion is about several subjects.
I have created a panel where I have asked people to partake in. I got SRS sampled adresses that have the same age and residence distribution as the country itself.
The first time I asked over 40.000 people and 3.000 wanted to join the panel.
The second time I asked around 20.000 people. but asked the 18-34 year olds two times more, because they don't respond that well and 4.000 people in total wanted to join.
The third time I asked around 8.000 people and asked the 18-34 year olds five times more. Around 2.500 wanted to join in total.

Now if I asks my panel something, they can refuse to answer. My final sample size is the responded people from my panel.

Are the chances of getting in the panel relevant for calculating the weights? If so, how do I calculate them?

I feel like the selection probability is the chance of being asked to answer a survey, but that is 100% for everyone in the panel.

I have information about the country itself and their people's age, gender, education and residence. This is also known for everyone in the panel.

There is some correlation between responding to a survey and living in specific places in said country.

Can somebody help me with this mess?

Comment: What kind of panel is this? Is it a survey panel maintained by a survey organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Decomposing the weight based on stages of sampling/nonresponse

The overall weight for a person is meant to represent the overall probability that a person in your target population had of taking the survey, accounting for random sampling as well as the probability that they responded to the survey, given that you asked them to. To determine this overall probability for person $i$, denoted $p_i$, we have to break the survey process into four distinct stages, each of which impacts the probability someone had of taking the survey.

Stages:

1. Random selection to invite a person to join the panel. $p_{1,i}$
2. Joining or declining to join the panel, given that they were selected $p_{2|1,i}$
3. Random selection of panel members who are requested to complete the particular survey, given that they joined the panel $p_{3|2,i}$
4. Response or nonresponse to the particular survey $p_{4|3,i}$, given that you requested that they complete the survey

As the survey designer, you control the random selection probabilities (stages 1 and 3) but you don't control the response/nonresponse probabilities (stages 2 and 4).

The overall probability for individual $i$ is thus:
$$ p_i = p_{1,i} \times p_{2|1,i} \times p_{3|2,i} \times p_{4|3,i} $$

The weight for this person is then $w_i = 1/p_i$. This weight is used to make sure that your estimates aren't biased as a result of oversampling some groups or because of some groups being more or less likely to take the survey.

It's common practice though to further adjust this weight using raking adjustments, which can help further reduce nonresponse bias as well as potentially reduce other kinds of bias such as coverage error.

#### Determining Stage-specific Probabilities

Because you designed the survey, you should know the value of $p_{1,i}$ and $p_{3|2,i}$ for everyone in your sample. For the stages of nonresponse, you have to estimate response propensities: that is, you have to estimate $p_{2|1,i}$ and $p_{4|3,i}$. Common approaches include logistic regression or using observed response rates for key demographic groups (e.g., if a person is from a racial/ethnic group with a 15% response rate, then you estimate that person's response propensity to be 15%).

This R package vignette gives an example of how to estimate response propensities and do weighting adjustments in R.

> https://bschneidr.github.io/svrep/articles/nonresponse-adjustments.html

#### References

Chapter 2 of “Applied Survey Data Analysis” provides an excellent overview of survey weighting to account for sampling probabilities and nonresponse.

> Heeringa, S., West, B., Berglund, P. (2017). Applied Survey Data Analysis, 2nd edition. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press.

Chapter 13 of “Practical Tools for Designing and Weighting Survey Samples” also provides an excellent overview of weighting methods to account for nonresponse.

> Valliant, R., Dever, J., Kreuter, F. (2018). Practical Tools for Designing and Weighting Survey Samples, 2nd edition. New York: Springer.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.